# Issue with open keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

**Scenario 1 :**

When I open my app

- Go to inside of `Fragment`
- Try enter digit it works well

**Scenario 2 :**

when i open my app

- Access `Navigation Drawer`
- Open `Fragment` from `Navigation Drawer`
- Return to main `Fragment`
- Go to inside of `Fragment` and try enter digit
- `Keyboard` not open

Answer (score 0):

You can manage force fully to show and hide keyboard by this way:

```
private void hideKeyBoard() {
    ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(invisibleEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

private void showKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(imm != null){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
    }
}
```